# Blackberry OS 6 & Websockets

Tags: html, blackberry, websocket

Does BlackBerry OS 6's HTML5 implementation support websockets?
There was a page on BB's developer portal where the supported tags were listed, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Anyone know if websockets are supported?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing and research throughout the web, I've come to conclude that websockets are not yet supported on BlackBerry devices.

Although some tests might indicate they're supported, the implementation is just a stub. Too bad.

Answer (score 0):

The list of supported tags can be found [here](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/08/blackberry-html5/).

Try [Mondernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) on your phone to check whether WebSockets are supported.

I think the only browser [supporting WebSockets](http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets) is iOS Safari 4.2.